# docker синхронизируемые папки

Tags: docker

Есть два немножко разных конфига. В первом в Dockerfile есть COPY который копирует всю папку с проектом, и затем в docker-compose делает вот так:

```
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro
      - /etc/group:/etc/group:ro
      - .:/app:cached
      - home-dir:/home/user:cached
    ports:
      - '4001:8080'
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - app-network
```

То есть можно заметить :ro и :cached. Чем это отличается от подхода, когда мы не делаем COPY в dockerfile и просто пишем пути в docker-compose наподобие - home-dir:/home/user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Слои (Layers).](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/)

Когда вы прописываете COPY в DockerFile то вы предполагаете что создается слой с файлами который будет уже принадлежать образу из которого у вас будут "подниматься" контейнеры. Т.е. если вы запустите контейнер, сделаете там изменения (изменения кстати говоря делаются в последнем слое, тот что называется слой контейнера) то при `docker-compose down`  и повторном запуске - изменения естественно пропадут, т.к. слой контейнера удаляется вместе с контейнером.

Подход когда вы прописываете [`volumes`](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) - это совсем другая история. Вы "биндиде" файлы и папки к слою контейнера и у вас изменения в них происходят в двустороннем направлении. Т.е. что то вы изменили снаружи - то же поменялось и внутри контейнера. Изменили внутри контейнера какую то из этих папок - поменяли снаружи. Ну и само собой после пересоздания контейнера все изменения сохраняются.

На самом деле я сознательно допускаю некоторую ошибку ибо существует и [bind](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) и [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) однако я попытался попросту передать идею. Уверен что из [документации](https://docs.docker.com/storage/) вам станет яснее.

Comment: а для чего :ro и :cached ?

Comment: @PaulWall ro очевидно это read only, чтоб нельзя было изменить данные внутри контейнера, а вот что касается cached - это насколько я понимаю исключительно для MacOs 

`cached: The macOS host’s view of the mount is authoritative. There may be delays before updates made on the host are visible within a container.`